# How to print random months in PHP

Tags: php, math

Is a function available in PHP, which can print random month?

Like mt_rand(); to print random number.

If NO, what will easy method to print random month?

I am using below code:

```
$randmo = mt_rand(1,12);
if($randmo == 1)
{
    $randmonth = "Jan";
}
elseif($randmo == 2)
{
    $randmonth = "Feb";
}
elseif($randmo == 3)
{
    $randmonth = "Mar";
}
elseif($randmo == 4)
{
    $randmonth = "Apr";
}
elseif($randmo == 5)
{
    $randmonth = "May";
}
elseif($randmo == 6)
{
    $randmonth = "Jun";
}
elseif($randmo == 7)
{
    $randmonth = "Jul";
}
elseif($randmo == 8)
{
    $randmonth = "Aug";
}
elseif($randmo == 9)
{
    $randmonth = "Sep";
}
elseif($randmo == 10)
{
    $randmonth = "Oct";
}
elseif($randmo == 11)
{
    $randmonth = "Nov";
}
else
{
    $randmonth = "Dec";
}
echo $randmonth;
```

First i am storing a rand number from 1 to 12 in $randmo variable. And printing using if else.
I am looking for better script.

Comment: 1. Make an array with your months 2. Chose a random element 3. print it. (Or as some users would say: There is no build_house(); function, but there are the tools to do it: hammer();)

Comment: Not really related to the question, but instead of multiple `if`s, you have the option to use the [switch...case](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Comment: I like answer of **Neel Ion** and comment of @Rizier123 . I will be more happy, if there will more fast and easy method. because i do not want to see **increase server response time**.

Comment: The cost of this even with a bunch of functions is negligible.  The response time would only matter if this is something you are doing thousands or more times in a script.  Avoid micro-optimization thinking or decisions.  You should only worry about that when required by performance related metrics, and then only with the benefit of profiling the app to see the big picture.  Stability, functionality and maintenance should be your first concerns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this. `array_rand()` function returns a random key of an array.

```
<?php

$months=array('january','february','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december');

$key=array_rand($months);

echo $months[$key];
```

Comment: To add: `if($months[$key] == "may"){

echo "It is May!!!";

}

else{
echo "Sorry, it is not May yet.";
}`

Comment: Nice $months = array('Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct');
 $key = array_rand($months);
 $randmonth = $months[$key];

Comment: You could put that inside a function and just `return $months[$key];` too.

Answer (score 5):

There are 12 months in a year.

```
$month = mt_rand(1, 12);
```

Sometimes, there is a tendency to overthink things.  You can combine this with the DateTime class to get whatever you specifically need.

Ok, let's go to extremes:

```
function getRandomMonth($fmt = 'abbreviated') {
    $formats = array(
        'abbreviated' => 'M',
        'numeric' => 'n',
        'full' => 'F'
    );

    // Insure we have a valid format
    $fmt = array_key_exists($fmt, $formats) ? $fmt : 'abbreviated';

    $tmp = '2000-' . sprintf('%02s', mt_rand(1, 12)) . '-01';
    $date = new DateTime($tmp);
    return $date->format($formats[$fmt]);
}

echo getRandomMonth() . "\n";
echo getRandomMonth('numeric') . "\n";
echo getRandomMonth('full') . "\n";
```

One output might be:

```
Nov
1
October
```

This is certainly not faster code than an array lookup, but it shows how this approach can easily provide more flexibility (long vs, short name).  What's even more interesting, is that with a few code adjustments, you could have a locale aware or internationalizable version of this by using [IntlDateFormatter](http://php.net/manual/en/intldateformatter.format.php) to provide you month names in different languages.

You would have to change the format strings if you wanted to go that route, as they require ISO standard strings, but this is documented in the php manual.